# Python Multiprocessing Example Not Printing

Tags: python

I have a very simple multiprocessing example that I found online (shown below). For some reason, when I execute it in Spyder, it doesn't print anything out at all. It doesn't hang either. I'm using Python 3.x. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_func(continent='Asia'):
    print('The name of continent is : ', continent)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # confirms that the code is under main function
    names = ['America', 'Europe', 'Africa']
    procs = []
    proc = Process(target=print_func)  # instantiating without any argument
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name in names:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(name,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Comment: If I run it in PyCharm and even run it in console with `python3 test.py` - it works well without any change. Something wrong with stdout in Spyder... Does it redirects it to file or somewhere else?

Comment: Hm yeah it seems something was wrong with Spyder. I had to run in the console in order for any output to show. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

When you in threads or other process you will not get its stdout, so if you want to log you better use python logging
documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

you can also check this for more solutions https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/